# Excel: CountIf Quandry

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2003, countif

Thanks for your help in advance!

So my problem is the following; I have a sheet which I use to log risks that come up in my project. They are graded from Critical to Low, and are either "Open" or "Closed". I want a formula that will count only the open actions which are critical. So far i've got =COUNTIF(Risks!E:E,"Critical"), which correctly counts the number of critical risks, but obviously doesn't take into account if they are open or closed. I tried using än IF statement at the start, but found that =IF(Risks!H:H="Open",COUNTIF(Risks!E:E,"Critical")) wasn't really returning what I needed.

I definitely remember getting this to work before, but I'm thinking perhaps I used VBA? Been a while since I've used excel!

Any help much appreciated!

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(Risks!E:E,"Critical",Risks!H:H,"Open")
```

[COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) allows the use of multiple criteria.

Comment: I ran that one through my sheet, and it came up with a #NAME? Error. A little investigation and I realised that because I'm forced to run the 2003 version of Excel...that function doesn't work. However thanks for the suggestion, I will try it with a newer version and see if I can get it to work there! Is it possible to replicate this function with perhaps another, 2003 friendly, formula? Cheers!

Comment: @JavaStarta Use `=SUMPRODUCT((Risks!$E$1:$E$100="Critical")*(Risks!$H$1:$H$100="Open"))` avoid full column references it will slow down the computation.