# Excel =CountIfs Not Giving Any Return

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to use the `=COUNTIFS` formula to track incoming post.  Column B is the date of incoming post, Column E is the date the post is worked.
I want to count the number of rows where column B is less than today’s date and column E is blank.

I am using the formula below however it is giving me a return of `0` where it should be thousands.

```
=COUNTIFS(Invoices!B:B,"<Today()",Invoices!E:E,"")
```

Based on an answer I got here:

[Excel: CountIf Quandry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697976/excel-countif-quandry)

I also tried formula below but again I am getting a 0 return.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Invoices!B:B = "<Today()")*(Invoices!E:E="")
```

Finally I tried both formulae with much smaller ranges but again to no avail.

Appreciate any insights you may have

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below formula will work, but you'll need to change the ranges to reflect your data set and maybe worksheet names.

The key to the below is combining the Today() function with the less than operator "<" by using an ampersand "&"

You also need to test column E for a blank value which is represented by blank quotation marks ""

```
=COUNTIFS(Invoices!B:B,"<"&TODAY(),Invoices!E:E,"")
```

Comment: Thanks Jiminy Cricket!

Comment: @Emma you can accept the answer by clicking the tick if it's worked for you so that future people searching will know it's given the correct result

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the `TODAY()` function outside of the quotation marks and concatenate it with the lesser than symbol. Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Invoices!B:B,"<"&TODAY(),Invoices!E:E,"")
```